# Questions and Articles are occasionally duplicated into two identical posts created in the same instant

Tags: bug, status-review, questions, duplicate-questions

I've noticed a number of incidences where a user posts the same question twice. However, these posts are created *within the same second* so this isn't a situation where a user keeps posting the same question to draw attention to it. Given the number of such incidents, I'm inclined to believe that either something in the client UI or the server is malfunctioning periodically and while this is a relatively uncommon occurrence, I feel like I've been seeing more flags about this lately.

I'm going to give a few examples, but am going to try to limit the meta effect somewhat by only linking directly to deleted posts. (If there is only one link then the post is either closed as a duplicate or has a comment to the duplicated post.)

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/77493613 (2023-11-16 2023-11-16 09:25:50Z; created 5 copies 77493613, 77493611, 77493615, 77493612)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/77452373 (2023-11-09 10:30:40Z)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/77375486 (2023-10-27 15:48:04Z)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/77365389 (2023-10-26 08:37:06Z)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/77362959 (2023-10-25 21:19:19Z)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/77348515 (2023-10-23 21:53:58Z)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/77330330 (2023-10-20 10:50:17Z)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/77329488, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77329489 (2023-10-20 08:42:13Z)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/77318326 (2023-10-18 17:05:56Z)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/77291605 (2023-10-14 04:17:52Z)

Here's an [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1795189/potential-duplicated-posts?StartDate=2020-01-01) which has lots of potential instances of this bug. There are some false positives, especially for questions that only have a language tag, but it appears to be primarily surfacing the correct pairs.

The oldest instance of this I've found is https://stackoverflow.com/q/48392977, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48392978 posted 2018-01-23 01:47:53Z. Queries extending prior to this are almost exclusively false positives.

It's may also be worth noting that I haven't found any incidences of this where the question was created through the Ask Wizard.

This has also affected articles, though such examples are harder to track down given their absence in SEDE:

- https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/azure/articles/76851768

---

When it's brought to moderator attention this is very easy to handle. Since the posts are identical, by the same user, even if it has received answers the posts can simply be merged together. We don't even get any confusing timestamps (like when answers appear to have been posted before the question was) since both copies of the question have the same CreationDate.

The issue here is primarily the poor user experiences. In some cases this is because curators/answerers are admonishing them for posting the same question multiple times when, in these cases, this is almost certainly not their intention.

In other cases, this is because when users try to close it as a duplicate it adds a comment "Does this answer your question?" which [can be confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/136352005) since, to the user, it appears to be a link to their own, same question. This confusion is, of course, because the pages are *identical* barring the Id of the post in the URL which is an extremely minor thing to notice.

It'd be great if this could be fixed to reduce the confusion and frustration this has caused. Additionally, it'd be great to reduce the number of posts requiring moderation. I've handled dozens of these posts (and am still working through the SEDE query) which were missed when they were initially posted and could've potentially never been handled.

I've been working primarily from [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1795249?StartDate=2018-01-01) which has a 100% true positive rate, but relies on OwnerUserId which means it only finds posts where both copies are still visible.

Comment: I've also been facing an issue recently with comments getting posted multiple times after clicking the "Add comment" button just once.  I used to think that might have just been a network problem but maybe it is related to this issue?

Comment: I saw a (self) answer with the exact same timestamp as the question. (I will find the reference to the pair eventually.)

Comment: I would assume that's just a normal self-answer @PeterMortensen There's even [a checkbox on the ask window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqxg4.png) that'll enable an answer window to create the Q&A pair simultaneously.

Comment: It's possible to perform the same review action on two different tasks simultaneously (without ever having seen the second one) by accidentally clicking the "Submit" button twice on the first task, if there's lag. Maybe the same thing could happen if the Ask Question button lags, the user assumes nothing happened with the first click, and clicks again?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this happens network-wide. Off the top of my head see [q1](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/61340/34330) and [q2](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/61339/34330) on Writing (both now deleted). There's no reason to allow two posts from the same user so close together, especially not with the same title and body.

Comment: Indeed @Laurel (I'll trust you since I can't see either of your linked questions). These can be found on lots of sites. For example, here are a couple of currently visible examples from SuperUser [Pair 1-1](https://superuser.com/q/1815463), [Pair 1-2](https://superuser.com/q/1815464) | [Pair 2-1](https://superuser.com/q/1816535), [Pair 2-2](https://superuser.com/q/1816536). I could've put it on MSE, but I thought I'd have a better chance of getting a status-review here.

Comment: I've been finding that I'm clearing out up to 6 or so of these a week on Stack Overflow. Though that's just what is left visible, I'm finding about up to 15 or so every week that have already been handled either by the Asker or community. Regardless, some kind of check should definitely be in place.

Comment: Cross-site Dupe:- [Sometimes, two identical copies of the same question get posted at the same time despite only submitting once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346338/1099857)

Comment: It looks like it can also create duplicate users on sites with unregistered accounts enabled. See these questions: [1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/281422/82909), [2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/281421/82909), and [3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/281420/82909). Poor Pauls.