# Make Articles available in SEDE

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, articles

I want to do data analysis on Articles. Seems at a glance like it should fit just fine as a new post type in the `Posts` table.

Comment: Maybe the title should be "Allow Articles to be selectable in SEDE" as I thought you wanted article functionality in SEDE... Like you wanted to write an article about SEDE for some reason... Maybe I just haven't had enough coffee today though :).

Comment: Articles should be pretty easy, as I have reasons to believe they are already in the Posts table in production but its PostType is not selected in the SEDE refresh

Comment: @rene I suspected so too, especially with the https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427072/11107541 bug